# Calculating averages from a subquery from referenced tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

DB fiddle playground with the query: https://dbfiddle.uk/-k2l2UK4

I’m learning SQL and only the fifth column is returning the incorrect value. I am trying to calculate the following information for a particular test variant:

- average time on page
- average bounce rate
- average scrolled down percentage
- average no. of forms submitted
- average no. of clicks on buttons and links

The first 4 seem to return the correct results from my query, although I can’t figure out what’s wrong with the 5th `avg_num_button_link_clicks` column which incorrectly returns a value of 3 instead of 0.33. I have this query, which is supposed to calculate the averages for the `test_tracking_data_sessions`, `test_tracking_data_forms` and `test_tracking_data_buttons_and_links` tables that relate to a `test_variants` record:

```
SELECT 
  AVG(time_on_page) AS avg_time_on_page,
  AVG(CASE WHEN bounced THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS avg_bounce_rate,
  AVG(scrolled_down_percentage) AS avg_scrolled_down_percentage,
  AVG(num_forms_submitted) AS avg_num_forms_submitted,
  SUM(num_button_link_clicks) / COUNT(DISTINCT data_id) AS avg_num_button_link_clicks
FROM (
  SELECT 
    ttds.id AS data_id,
    ttds.time_on_page,
    ttds.bounced,
    ttds.scrolled_down_percentage,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN ttdf.id IS NOT NULL THEN ttdf.id END) AS num_forms_submitted,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN ttdbl.id IS NOT NULL THEN ttdbl.id END) AS num_button_link_clicks
  FROM test_tracking_data_sessions ttds
  LEFT JOIN test_tracking_data_forms ttdf ON ttdf.data_id = ttds.id AND ttdf.submitted
  LEFT JOIN test_tracking_data_buttons_and_links ttdbl ON ttdbl.data_id = ttds.id
  WHERE ttds.variant_id = 1
  GROUP BY ttds.id
) subquery;
```

For example, values 10000, 0.33, 40, 0.66 and 0.33 should be returned for the `avg_time_on_page`, `avg_bounce_rate`, `avg_scrolled_down_percentage`, `avg_num_forms_submitted` and `avg_num_button_link_clicks` columns based on the following data:

```
INSERT INTO test_variants (id, name, test_id, page_id, is_control, variant_no, css_code, js_code, is_redirect, traffic_allocation, created_at) VALUES
  (1, 'Control I', 1, 1, true, 0, NULL, NULL, FALSE, 30, NOW());

INSERT INTO test_tracking_data_sessions (id, test_id, variant_id, goal_id, session_start, session_end, time_on_page, bounced, scrolled_down_percentage, device_type_id) VALUES
  ('bf5a5afe-82d2-4007-92b8-2985bc4c6cea', 1, 1, 1, '2023-02-01 10:00:00', '2023-02-01 10:10:00', 2000, true, 0, 3),
  ('00c7fc33-d189-4bd8-b293-447adf618919', 1, 1, 1, '2023-02-02 11:00:00', '2023-02-02 11:10:00', 10000, false, 30, 3),
  ('5e9cc392-f336-410d-83fb-726f95971259', 1, 1, 1, '2023-02-03 11:30:00', '2023-02-03 11:40:00', 18000, false, 90, 1);

INSERT INTO test_tracking_data_forms (data_id, name, submitted)
VALUES 
    ('bf5a5afe-82d2-4007-92b8-2985bc4c6cea', 'Form 1', true),
    ('00c7fc33-d189-4bd8-b293-447adf618919', 'Form 2', false),
    ('5e9cc392-f336-410d-83fb-726f95971259', 'Form 3', true);

INSERT INTO test_tracking_data_buttons_and_links (data_id, name, clicks)
VALUES 
    ('bf5a5afe-82d2-4007-92b8-2985bc4c6cea', 'Button 1', 1),
    ('bf5a5afe-82d2-4007-92b8-2985bc4c6cea', 'Link 1', 1),
    ('bf5a5afe-82d2-4007-92b8-2985bc4c6cea', 'Link 2', 0),
    ('00c7fc33-d189-4bd8-b293-447adf618919', 'Button 1', 0),
    ('00c7fc33-d189-4bd8-b293-447adf618919', 'Link 1', 0),
    ('00c7fc33-d189-4bd8-b293-447adf618919', 'Link 2', 0),
    ('5e9cc392-f336-410d-83fb-726f95971259', 'Button 1', 1),
    ('5e9cc392-f336-410d-83fb-726f95971259', 'Link 1', 0),
    ('5e9cc392-f336-410d-83fb-726f95971259', 'Link 2', 0);
```

However, there is a problem with the query, in that the `avg_num_button_link_clicks` wrongly returns 3 instead of 0.33. Since there are a total of 3 clicks and there are a total of 9 records, the value should be 3/9 (which is 0.33) for the `avg_num_button_link_clicks`.

My tables:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test_variants(
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  test_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  page_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  is_control BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
  variant_no INTEGER NOT NULL, -- control must be 0
  css_code TEXT,
  js_code TEXT,
  is_redirect BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
  traffic_allocation INTEGER NOT NULL,
  created_at TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
  last_modified TIMESTAMPTZ
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test_tracking_data_sessions(
    id UUID PRIMARY KEY ,
    test_id INTEGER,
    variant_id INTEGER REFERENCES test_variants(id) ON DELETE CASCADE, -- control is also technically a variant
    goal_id INTEGER,
    session_start TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    session_end TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    time_on_page INTEGER NOT NULL,
    bounced BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
    scrolled_down_percentage INTEGER,
    device_type_id INTEGER 
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test_tracking_data_forms(
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    data_id UUID REFERENCES test_tracking_data_sessions(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    submitted BOOLEAN NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test_tracking_data_buttons_and_links(
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    data_id UUID REFERENCES test_tracking_data_sessions(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    clicks INTEGER NOT NULL
);
```

Does anyone know what I’m doing wrong here? I feel like I’m almost there, and it could be something simple that I’m doing wrong.

Comment: COUNT(DISTINCT data_id) / SUM( 1.0 * num_button_link_clicks)  instead of SUM(num_button_link_clicks) / COUNT(DISTINCT data_id) AS avg_num_button_link_clicks ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your sample data it appears you should be using the sum of the number of clicks, you are just looking for not-null values on the outer join, which counts all rows, not just clicks.

In your subquery try using a sum of the `clicks` column and dividing it by the total number of rows,

```
SELECT 
  AVG(time_on_page) AS avg_time_on_page,
  AVG(CASE WHEN bounced THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS avg_bounce_rate,
  AVG(scrolled_down_percentage) AS avg_scrolled_down_percentage,
  AVG(num_forms_submitted) AS avg_num_forms_submitted,
  SUM(num_button_link_clicks) / sum(TotalNum) as avg_num_button_link_clicks
FROM (
  SELECT 
    ttds.id AS data_id,
    ttds.time_on_page,
    ttds.bounced,
    ttds.scrolled_down_percentage,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN ttdf.id IS NOT NULL THEN ttdf.id END) AS num_forms_submitted,
    SUM(ttdbl.clicks) AS num_button_link_clicks,
    COUNT(ttdbl.id) TotalNum
  FROM test_tracking_data_sessions ttds
  LEFT JOIN test_tracking_data_forms ttdf ON ttdf.data_id = ttds.id AND ttdf.submitted
  LEFT JOIN test_tracking_data_buttons_and_links ttdbl ON ttdbl.data_id = ttds.id
  WHERE ttds.variant_id = 1
  GROUP BY ttds.id
) subquery;
```

Comment: Legend - it works! Thank you! Should the same principle be applied to the `avg_num_forms_submitted`? I wonder whether it just works out of fluke, but I am not sure

Comment: although it isn't a number so not sure that `COUNT` would work on it